# Higher order functions that don't take any parameters being resolved

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Why is this illegal:

```
def foobar() = {}

val option: Option[() => Unit] = Some(foobar)
```

Whereas this is legal:

```
def foobar() = {}

val intermediate: () => Unit = foobar

val option: Option[() => Unit] = Some(intermediate)
```

In the first example, the compiler complains that the right side of the assignment is of type `Option[Unit]` rather than `Option[() => Unit]`.

I suspect this has something do with `foobar` being evaluated rather than being passed as a variable to `Some()`, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Actually for both case I'm getting the same results: `option: Option[() => Unit] = Some(<function0>)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because parentheses are optional when evaluating an empty-parens method. By convention, they're left off for pure methods, but that's just convention. So you're right, it's actually evaluating foobar instead of eta-expanding it to a function. You can fix your first example by explicitly invoking eta expansion with the underscore operator:

```
val option: Option[() => Unit] = Some(foobar _)
```

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I feel like the compiler *should* be able to infer what I meant in that case, but I can see how it could be ambiguous.